# Strange behavior when hovering/clicking an element

Tags: html, css

I get a really strange behavior on a very simple html landing page.

The page is the following: http://fw2019.gosrl.webfactional.com/

If you try to click on any link (FB icon, Instagram icon, years of the previous edition) the yellow shape on the background suddenly move to the right.

The page is pure html + css, with no javascript attached.

I've tried to:
- deactivate any transition/animation when hovering Social Icons
- check if I get the same behavior at a lower resolution -> YES

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", arial, sans-serif;
}

.main-image {}

.main-image img {
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper,
.fake-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1636px;
  height: 562px;
  background: url(/wp-content/asset/grid-svg-4-01.svg);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 99;
}

.fake-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  left: 50%;
  top: -130px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 56;
}

.content-wrapper p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.content-wrapper h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.main-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.titolo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 772px;
  height: 208px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 176px;
  left: 345px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 32px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  font-family: titling-gothic-fb-wide, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 70px;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: left;
}

.logo-container {
  background: #000;
  width: 171px;
  height: 138px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1120px;
  top: 212px;
  padding: 28px;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  z-index: 999;
}

.logo-container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.sponsor-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 260px;
  top: 37px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 428px;
  height: 68px;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}

.date-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 944px;
  left: 346px;
  top: 422px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
  font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

.date-container>div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 56px;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.date-container .light {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.date-container .bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.blue-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 256px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 157, 255, 1);
  position: absolute;
  background-position: -2px -2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  height: 138px;
  z-index: 0 !important;
  animation-name: enlarge;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes enlarge {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 560px;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px);
  }
}

.red-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 2px;
  height: 558px;
  width: 562px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ff003f;
  background-position: 130px 136px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1000000px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.skate-park {
  /* width: 1636px;
        height: 1200px; */
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: url(http://fw2019.gosrl.webfactional.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/skate-bg-2.png);
  /* left: -47px;)
        top: 102px; */
  background-size: cover;
  top: -45px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.fake-content-wrapper#circle {
  top: 203px;
}

.fake-content-wrapper#rect {
  top: 333px;
}

.content-wrapper#skate {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: -10%;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 200vw;
  position: fixed;
}

.content-wrapper#skate .skate-park {
  position: relative;
  /* top: -140px; */
}


/* ANIMAZIONE */


/* .blue-box {
        animation-name: bluebox;
        animation-duration: 20s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes bluebox {
      0% {transform: translate(0,0);}
      6.39% {transform: translate(0,-210px);}
      43.61% {transform: translate(-1376px,-210px);}
      55.58% {transform: translate(-1376px,210px);}
      92.8% {transform: translate(0px,210px);}
      100% {transform: translate(0px,0);}
    } */

.previous h3,
.previous a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.previous a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.previous h3 {
  font-family: titling-gothic-fb-narrow, sans-serif;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.previous a {
  font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.previous a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.content-wrapper#footer {
  overflow: visible;
  background: none;
}

.previous,
.social {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.social {
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}

.social img {
  height: 30px;
}

.social a {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.social a img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}


/* .social a:hover img {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    } */

@media screen and (max-width: 1919px) and (min-width: 1366px) {
  .content-wrapper,
  .fake-content-wrapper {
    width: 1292px;
  }
  .titolo,
  .date-container {
    left: 173px;
  }
  .date-container {
    width: 772px;
    left: 174px;
  }
  .logo-container {
    left: 948px;
  }
  .fake-content-wrapper#circle {
    top: 196px;
  }
  .fake-content-wrapper#rect {
    top: 326px;
  }
  /* .skate-park {
     left: -360px; 
    } */
  .date-container>div {
    font-size: 46px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .blue-box {
    bottom: -200px;
    top: auto;
    width: 170px;
  }
  @keyframes enlarge {
    from {
      height: 0;
    }
    to {
      height: 760px;
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1365px) and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .content-wrapper {
    width: 862px;
  }
  .sponsor-container {
    right: 88px;
  }
  .titolo,
  .date-container {
    left: 1px;
    width: 686px;
  }
  .date-container {
    left: 2px;
  }
  .date-container>div {
    font-size: 40px;
    left: 2px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
  }
  .blue-box {
    bottom: 2px;
    top: auto;
    width: 170px;
  }
  .logo-container {
    left: 689px;
  }
  .content-wrapper#skate {
    left: -20%;
    width: 200%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .content-wrapper {
    width: 604px;
  }
  .sponsor-container {
    right: 2px;
  }
  .titolo {
    left: 1px;
    font-size: 60px;
    width: 600px;
  }
  .date-container {
    left: 2px;
    width: 600px;
  }
  .date-container>div {
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
  }
  .logo-container {
    left: 2px;
    top: 37px;
  }
  .blue-box {
    width: 170px;
  }
  .content-wrapper#skate {
    left: -30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 375px) {
  .content-wrapper {
    width: 346px;
  }
  .titolo {
    left: 1px;
    font-size: 41px;
    line-height: 43px;
    height: 138px;
    width: 342px;
    padding-top: 8px;
  }
  .logo-container {
    top: 37px;
    left: 2px;
  }
  .date-container {
    width: 342px;
    left: 2px;
    top: 352px;
    padding: 4.5px;
  }
  .date-container>div {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .sponsor-container {
    left: 2px;
    width: 342px;
    bottom: 37px;
    top: auto;
  }
  .sponsor-container img {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .previous h3 {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .previous {
    bottom: -60px;
  }
  .blue-box {
    width: 170px;
  }
  .content-wrapper#skate {
    left: -50%;
  }
  .skate-park {
    top: -100px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 150vw;
  }
  .titolo {
    font-size: 32px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 374px) {
  .content-wrapper {
    width: 259.5px;
  }
  .logo-container {
    top: 37px;
    left: 2px;
  }
  .titolo {
    left: 1px;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 32px;
    width: 256px;
    height: 173px;
  }
  .date-container {
    left: 2px;
    width: 256px;
    top: 387px;
    height: 68px;
  }
  .date-container>div {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 21px;
  }
  .sponsor-container {
    width: 256px;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    top: auto;
  }
  .sponsor-container img {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 8px;
  }
  .previous h3 {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .previous {
    bottom: -60px;
  }
  .blue-box {
    width: 84px;
  }
  .content-wrapper#skate {
    left: -50%;
    width: 400vw;
  }
  .previous {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    text-align: right;
    bottom: -100px;
  }
  .social {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .skate-park {
    left: 200px;
  }
  .main-content {
    align-items: baseline;
  }
  body {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .content-wrapper#skate {
    top: 0;
  }
  .content-wrapper#skate {
    top: -400px;
  }
}


/* CELL ORIZZONTALI */

@media screen and (max-height: 500px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .main-content {
    align-items: baseline;
  }
  body {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .content-wrapper#skate {
    top: 0;
  }
}


/* RETINA */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
(min-width: 1921px) {
  .skate-park {
    left: 13.5%;
    top: -10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Festiwall 2019 | 9 - 15 Settembre 2019 | Ragusa</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/qse6gsn.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Space+Mono:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="content-wrapper" id="circle">
        <div class="red-circle"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-wrapper" id="skate">
        <div class="skate-park"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-wrapper" id="rect">
        <div class="blue-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h2 class="titolo">Public Art<br>Festival</h2>
        <div class="logo-container">
          <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/festiwall-2019-logo.png" alt="Festiwall 2019 logo">
        </div>
        <div class="sponsor-container">
          <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/festiwall-2019-sponsor.png" alt="Festiwall 2019 Sponsor">
        </div>
        <div class="date-container">
          <div class="light">09/15</div>
          <div class="bold">September</div>
          <div class="light">2019</div>
          <div class="bold">Ragusa</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-wrapper" id="footer">
        <div class="social">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/RagusaFestiWall/" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/fw2019-icons-_0001_fb.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/festiwall_rg/" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/fw2019-icons-_0000_inst.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="previous">
          <h3>Edizioni precedenti</h3>
          <a href="http://www.festiwall.it/2015" title="Festiwall 2015">2015</a> / <a href="http://www.festiwall.it/2016" title="Festiwall 2016">2016</a> / <a href="http://www.festiwall.it/2017" title="Festiwall 2017">2017</a> / <a href="http://www.festiwall.it/2018"
            title="Festiwall 2016">2018</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for those who are willing to give support :)
Antonio

Comment: This is somewhere to look: `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-width: 1921px)
.skate-park {
    left: 13.5%;
    top: -10%;
}`

Comment: I think your problem is this: `.main-container{ display: table }`. Change it to `.main-container{ display: block }` and it should work. Not 100% sure what the actual problem is, but display:table can lead to such unexpected behaviors

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is not the case: I've commented the rule but still I get the same error.

Comment: @elveti, that fixed the issue. Amazing! I've also seen the error was only present in Chrome. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Antonio glad to hear that fixed it! But sorry, no idea what caused this. I tried to look for open Chrome/Webkit bugs with `display:table` but didn't find anything meaningful. I'd guess it's caused by using `display: table` with `display:flex` on a child. `Flex` is still pretty new, so there can still be undiscovered bugs. So congrats! You probably just found a Chrome bug :P

Comment: @elveti, thank you again. If you add the answer, I can give you a one-up :)